# How to prove a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $(X, \rho)$ is a metric space.
 Show that $\forall (x,  y) \in X$,   $\sigma(x,  y) = 2\rho (x, y)$ is also a metric space in X.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know the axioms that define a metric space?

Comment: Have you tried to prove this? All you need is the definition - everything you need to prove about $\sigma$ is clear from corresponding facts about $\rho$.

Answer (score 2):

We check the conditions of a metric space. (Some of these are redundant, but I wanted to be thorough so you can just look at the conditions below that are in the definition of a metric that you use in your course.)

- Non-negativity: Clearly $\forall x,y\in X$, we see that $\sigma(x,y)=2\rho(x,y) \geq 0$ since $\rho$ is a metric. (This one follows from the following three properties, however, and can probably be left out.)
- Symmetry: Clearly $\forall x,y \in X$, we see that $\sigma(x,y) = 2\rho(x,y) = 2\rho(y,x) = \sigma(y,x)$ since $\rho$ is a metric.
- Identity of indiscernibles: Clearly $\forall x,y\in X$, we see that $\sigma(x,x) = 2\rho(x,x) = 0$ and likewise if $0 = \sigma(x,y) = 2\rho(x,y)$ then $x=y$ since $\rho$ is a metric.
- Triangle inequality: Clearly $\forall x,y,z\in X$, we see that $\sigma(x,z) = 2\rho(x,z) \leq 2\rho(x,y) + 2\rho(y,z) = \sigma(x,y) + \sigma(y,z)$ since $\rho$ is a metric.

Then we have shown that $\sigma$ satisfies all of the necessary conditions to be a metric and hence $(X,\sigma)$ is a metric space.